# Struggling with Oracle dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, dynamic-sql

I'm working on an Oracle procedure that needs to be very automated, and so I'm using dynamic SQL.  I'm new to using dynamic SQL.

I'm using a varchar2 variable to build the SQL that needs to be executed.  I've used a dbms_output to capture the SQL that's being generated, and it executes fine:

sql to create Basket Swap table = CREATE TABLE INBOUND.BASKET_CTAS_SWP COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH  AS SELECT * FROM INBOUND.BASKET_FCT  PARTITION (SYS_1234);

However, when I execute the procedure using this, it generates the error below

```
Execute MyProcedure;
```

Thank you for any guidance!

oracle version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

IDE: Oracle SQL Developer Version 4.0.2.15 Build 15.21

Code:

```
note: all variables set at beginning of procedure...
Sqlexec:= 'CREATE TABLE ' || Basket_Swap_Schema ||  '.' || Basket_Swap_Table_Name  || ' ';
Sqlexec:= Sqlexec || 'COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH  ';
Sqlexec:= Sqlexec || 'AS SELECT * FROM ' || Basket_Source_Schema_Name || '.' || Basket_Source_Table_Name || '  ';
Sqlexec:= Sqlexec || 'PARTITION ('||Basket_Partition_To_Process||'); ';

Dbms_Output.Put_Line('sql to create Basket Swap table = ' || Sqlexec);

Execute Immediate Sqlexec;
```

**Error Message:**

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
Execute Process_Wic_Snap_Partition
Error report -
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at "MY_SCHEMA.MY_PROCEDURE", line 102
ORA-06512: at line 1
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is fine but with DynamicSQL you're not allowed to have a semicolon at the end of your statement. Change the line `Sqlexec:= Sqlexec || 'PARTITION ('||Basket_Partition_To_Process||'); ';`
 to not include the semicolon at the end of the statement: `Sqlexec:= Sqlexec || 'PARTITION ('||Basket_Partition_To_Process||')';`